# ImportError: No module named responses

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm running py.tests from a virtual env. getting

```
ImportError: No module named responses
```

after pip freeze i see responses are installed

```
pip freeze                                                   ✱
cookies==2.2.1
funcsigs==1.0.2
mock==2.0.0
pbr==1.10.0
py==1.4.31
pymongo==2.7.2
pytest==2.9.2
requests==2.10.0
responses==0.5.1
six==1.10.0
```

Running tests :

```
like so py.test --verbose tests/
```

Comment: what does pip3 freeze say?

Comment: pip3 freeze                                                  ✱
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
cookies==2.2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
mimerender==0.5.4
pbr==0.10.7
pipdeptree==0.4.2
pymongo==2.7.2
python-dateutil==2.4.0
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
requests==2.5.1
responses==0.5.1
six==1.9.0
stevedore==1.2.0
virtualenv==12.0.5
virtualenv-clone==0.2.5
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.2

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I'm using nose in my django project.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this arises from the error when installing responses:

```
ERROR: responses 0.12.1 has requirement urllib3>=1.25.10, but you'll have urllib3 1.22 which is incompatible.
```

If you do update `urllib3` you get this error:

```
ERROR: requests 2.18.4 has requirement urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1, but you'll have urllib3 1.26.2 which is incompatible.
```

[Yet another reason to move to httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org)

So what you can do is install the older `responses` version:

```
responses<0.10.8
```